# admin edit.php saves but doesn't retrieve data from "params" database field

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I have a config.xml with some parameters for my component.

I need to define these parameters for each individual item.

So in admin/models/forms/myview.xml, I've written my fields:

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="params" label="JGLOBAL_FIELDSET_DISPLAY_OPTIONS">
    ...etc
```

and in my admin/tables/myview.php, inside the "bind" function

```
if (isset($array['params']) && is_array($array['params']))
{
    // Convert the params field to a string.
    $parameter = new JRegistry;
    $parameter->loadArray($array['params']);
    $array['params'] = (string)$parameter;
}
```

The form is able to save data "params" in the database, but doesn't retrieve any params if saved.

Comment: It's unclear how you're retrieving data from database.

Comment: This is the question ... the data is saved in the dbase but the relative fields of the form are not populated

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the behaviour, I've deleted this function:

```
public function getItem($pk = null)
{
    if ($item = parent::getItem($pk))
    {
        if (isset($item->params))
        {
            $item->params = json_encode($item->params);
        }
    }
    return $item;
}
```